# Delphi memo lines in one line

Tags: delphi, memo

In a TMemo field I have 3 lines:

1. line1
2. line2
3. line3

Is it posible to get all three lines as one string?

Example:

line1,line2,line3

Comment: Whoa, why all the downvotes? Just tell this guy how to improve his question if you think something is wrong

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Lines.CommaText property for this. Do the following:

```
CommaString := Memo1.Lines.CommaText;
```

Its also useful to use the DelimitedText property if you want the text to make use of another separator character. You can do that by using something like this:

```
Memo1.Lines.Delimiter := '-';
Memo1.Lines.StrictDelimiter := True;
DashString := Memo1.Lines.DelimitedText;
```

This works both ways. You can assign a value to the CommaText or DelimiterText to set the lines. This is actually a of TStringList so it will work with TListBox, TMemo, TComboBox, etc. Basically anything that uses a string list internally.

Comment: Yes i now that, but i don't wan't comma at the end of the line. I want to combine (join) all three lines into one line.

Comment: You shouldn't get a comma at the end of the text. Have you tried Memo1.Text := Memo1.Lines.CommaText to put the three lines back into the same Memo?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this suits your needs

```
d:=memo1.lines.count;
for i:=1 to d do
   memo1.lines[0]:=memo1.lines[0]+' '+memo1.lines[i];
for i:=1 to d do
   memo1.lines.Delete(1);
```

Answer (score -4):

here is a 3 line function that do it.

```
function getOneLineMemo(memo:Tmemo):String;
var
  i:integer;
begin
  result := '';
  for i:=0 to memo1.lines.count do
     result := result + memo.lines[0];
end;
```

Comment: Did you test this? I don't like to down vote, but this answer is a bad advice. It would show the first line 4 lines without comma's `line1line1line1line1`. That's not what was asked.

Comment: @Graymatter: no, it won't... You'll see it when you re-read it

Comment: `memo.lines[0]` will always return the value in the first line, surely you meant `i` and not `0`.

Comment: @Graymatter I thought that too, until I saw something else

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick Ouch, see what you mean. Crash saved by the typo which breaks it another way :)